# Displaying and selecting from a HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

Currently I have a Category and Post model, joined by a HABTM relationship.

Posts belong to multiple categories and have many attributes.

Categories just have a Name Property.

How do I create a multi-select form in my Posts _form.html.erb so I can select which categories I want the post to be assigned to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use bold and italics sparingly, if at all, in your question's text. Like typing in all caps, they're like yelling, and really only distract instead of help. Think of SO like it's an encyclopedia of programming problems Q&A, only mixed with a Wikipedia editing style. Write it like you'd see in a reference book,  concise, clear, and not overly decorated. It's ok to be friendly but it isn't a conversation.  Also, we don't use salutations ("Hi"), valedictions ("Thanks") or signatures ("Jonathan") in the questions or answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :category_ids, "Categories" %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `select` and `collection`. You may have to change the collection, not sure exactly what Category options you want to be able to choose from. Something like this:

```
<%= f.input :post, as: :select, collection: Category.posts, include_blank:false %>
```

Or checkout out the `collection_select` form helper method 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select